# Logical Validity of predicate logic argument

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

How can the logical validity of the following argument be proved?

$$\forall x\mathbb P(x, x)\wedge\forall x\forall y(\mathbb P(x, y)\rightarrow\forall z(\mathbb P(x, z)\vee\mathbb P(y, z)))\rightarrow\forall x\forall y(\mathbb P(x, y)\vee\mathbb P(y, x))$$

I have thought of using the Tableaux but I am a beginner in discrete maths. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Tableau proof will do:

1) $∀xP(x,x) ∧ ∀x∀y(P(x,y) → ∀z(P(x,z) ∨ P(y,z)))$ --- premise

2) $\lnot ∀x∀y(P(x, y) ∨ P(y, x))$ --- negation of the conclusion

3) $\lnot (P(a, b) ∨ P(b, a))$ --- from 2): $a$ and $b$ new

4) $\lnot P(a, b)$ --- from 3)

5) $\lnot P(b,a)$ --- from 3)

6) $P(a,a)$ --- from 1)

7) $P(a,a) → ∀z(P(a,z) ∨ P(a,z))$ --- from 1)

8a) $\lnot P(a,a)$ --- left branch from 7), using $\to$-rule: **closed** with 6)

8b) $∀z(P(a,z) ∨ P(a,z))$ --- right branch from 7), using $\to$-rule

9) $P(a,b) ∨ P(a,b)$ --- **closed** with 4).

Comment: do you know any good sources , where I can learn how to apply tableau proof for predicate logic, besides wikipedia (which I cannot understand their explanation)

Comment: why would you take the negation of P(a,a) in step 8a , when there is no  ¬P(a,a) before?

Comment: @Maverick98 - you can see Smullyan, [FO Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=kgvhQ-oSZiUC&printsec=frontcover), Smith, [An Intro to Formal Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=bX91C6GOBkcC&printsec=frontcover), Simpson, [Math Log](http://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/notes/logic.pdf).

Comment: The rule is: the le that for unpacking $\to$: $P \to Q$ is TRUE either if $P$ is FALSE or $Q$ is TRUE. Thus, we have to add two branches: one for $\lnot P$ and the other for $Q$.